# OrganizationServiceProxy via reverse proxy - Basic authentication

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, reverse-proxy, basic-authentication

Is it possible to use Dynamics CRM OrganizationServiceProxy via reverse proxy that requires Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes. If the client is X, the proxy is Y and CRM's OrganizationService endpoint is Z it is possible to have:</strike>

`X->Y->Z`

where Y requires Basic Auth and Y then makes requests to Z. If the proxy is .net based you can reference the [CRM SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453(v=crm.7).aspx) to make calls to CRM easier, authenticating most likely as a single account (that has the ability to [act on behalf of another user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309629.aspx) if necessary).

**EDIT:** I don't believe this will work as the request to CRM wouldn't include the Authorization header with basic auth creds.

Comment: In my situation, Y is .net based (it's a asp.net web api that use CRM SDK) and it calls Z, but between Y and Z is reverse proxy (P) that filters requests to Z based on IP address etc. and it requires Basic authentication. 
So, X->Y->P->Z